# Unit testing singletons

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, singleton

I have a singleton that contains reference to statistics object.

When I run couple of unit test on the program that uses that singleton - the values sustained between the tests.

I though that when I'm doing Program.Main() it all starts over between unit tests, but somehow it remembers the results from last test.

How can I write unit tests that will be isolated from each other (I don't want clean() functions - I want it to start over with new "everything"),

Comment: add some example of code please

Comment: This is one of the problems with singletons :)  You can reset the singleton (typically by using reflection to set the _instance pointer to null), or you need to look at loading it into it's own app domain for testing...

Comment: @forsvarir: That's a correct answer. Why post it as a comment?

Comment: @razelbe: I'd say it's not an answer, it's an observation and a pointer in the right direction.  An answer would have a bit more substance :0)

Comment: Which unit testing framework are you using?

Comment: @forsvarir: Fair enough. But you don't get rep from my comment upvote. :)

Comment: @razelbe: true, but if you get 4 of your friends to upvote it, I'll be a tenth of the way to a pundits badge

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Short version: do not write your singletons as singletons. Write them as normal classes, and call them via an Inversion of Control container, where you have configured the class to be a singleton instead.

That way, you can unit-test the class just fine and if you decide today or tomorrow that singleton is not the right lifestyle for the class, simply modify the configuration of the IoC container.

Comment: I'll check this inversion of control container - though I don't have time to invest in that. In the end, there is still a singleton, and I'll verify how this design pattern solve this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a post about that here: http://pvlerick.github.io/2017/03/how-to-get-rid-of-a-singleton

TL;DR:

1. Extract an interface from the Singleton (even if you don't own it) and make your class work against that interface instead of the Singleton's instance;
2. Depending on whether you own the Singleton or not, you can make it implement that interface or you'll need a simple adapter.

Comment: Creating a new `AppDomain` per test is quite hard. NUnit, for example, creates a new AppDomain per test session (one pass through all selected tests). NUnit then has to inject its code into that `AppDomain` to run the tests. That's non-trivial. You can't just create a new one and expect things to magically run in it. You have to get your code to run in it. Overall this answer has possibilities but I don't agree with the "which shouldn't be too difficult part".

Answer (score 2):

When attempting to test the singleton itself the following could be a possible solution:

```
public class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton _Instance;

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if (_Instance == null)
        {
            _Instance = new Singleton();
        }

        return _Instance;
    }

    private Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static resetForTesting() {
        _Instance = null
    }
}
```

So, in your unit testing framework you would call `Singleton.resetForTesting()` before each unit test.

**Note**: the downside of this approach is that there is no code level restriction that would stop somebody from invoking this method within production code even though it is only meant to be used with testing code. So, you would have to rely on documentation to convey that to other people.

Comment: You could add a restriction by making the `resetForTesting` method internal and making internals visible to your assembly containing your test classes. See this [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=net-5.0).

Answer (score 1):

look at this [Unit testing with singletons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085953/unit-testing-with-singletons)

also I would reccomand to use the mocking frameworks like [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/)

for isolation your test

Comment: that question you've linked to is about an exception the OP was getting, but the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085953/unit-testing-with-singletons/2085988#2085988) to that question contains a lot of useful links relevant to the question here. You might want to update your hyperlink.

Comment: Indeed. I'm trying to help you to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add property setter to your singleton class that will reassign singleton instance. This way in tests you can stub/mock your singleton.