# Is there any way to set a boost test suite to be last in one executed?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

Using boost 1.33.1 unit tests on Fedora7.

Our code base uses many singletons, so therefore it is not possible to create completely 'clean' unit tests.

What I would like to do is have a test that is executed after all the other tests to make sure the previous tests have tidied up after themselves.

I've tried naming a test suite and the file  AAAFinalTest or ZZZFinalTest.  But it always appears at the same position.  It's probably a link order thing.

Is there any way to force the test to the end?

Comment: I would suggest trying to avoid using singletons, because it hampers effective unit testing (among other things).  See some of the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085953/unit-testing-with-singletons.

Comment: The singleton pattern is not really the problem.  The problem is I want to make sure that there are no left overs from one test that interfere with another. 

Hmm, yes the problem is the singletons, but I can't really change the code at this point in the project.

Comment: I have a project with a bunch of singletons in it. They will be phased out some day, but that is another day. For now, I added a "SetInstance()" that I call in the setup for certain tests. Not pretty, but it helps making sane tests.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use global fixture?

You will not be able to use testing tools, but you can always report a misuse into std::err or do an assert.

Comment: I don't believe global fixtures are available in 1.33 !