# Javascript Module Pattern Singleton & Unit Testing

Tags: javascript, singleton, module-pattern

I'm using the standard javascript module pattern as described [here](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/). The problem I'm facing is that this method creates a singleton which can't be instantiated. Unit tests share the same state which basically renders them useless. Writing a teardown function for every module seems pretty tedious, I'm sure there is a better way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit testing with singletons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085953/unit-testing-with-singletons)