# Unit test for Scala object (not class)

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I've a singleton class in Scala that's declared as an 'object'. I need to write unit tests that 'mock' methods in this object. How do I do it? I tried using 'PowerMockRunner' etc with no luck.

For example:

```
object MyClass extends Serializable {
   def apply(): Unit = { ..... }
   def more methods....
}
```

Now I need to write a unit test that mocks the 'apply' method. How do I do it?

Comment: Please check out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZasXwtTRkio. Note - although I did not understand this video the first 2-3 times that I saw it, I learned from it the value of simply passing arguments to a function (to achieve DI). You should not need to mock this method using some `mockito` trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer - You shouldn't unit-test singletons.

The long is here - [Unit testing with singletons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085953/unit-testing-with-singletons).

You can extract the functionality to a trait and unit-test the trait.

Not sure why you need the `extends Serializable` but left it just to show what I mean

```
  object MyClass extends Serializable with TheFunctionality {
  // whatever you need here
  }

  trait TheFunctionality {
    def apply(): Unit = ???
  }
```

Comment: Also they can have the same name. `trait Foo; object Foo extends Foo`