# Java singleton - Writing a unit test for the class?

Tags: java, junit, singleton, mockito

I have a java class - very typical of the usual singleton - like this :

PLEASE NOTE : I have left out the "if null" logic here, for the sake of brevity, because that isn't what I am having trouble with, and I don't want to crowd the question.

```
public class MySingleton
{
    ObjectMapper mapper;

    private MySingleton()
    {
        new MySingleton(new ObjectMapper())
    }

    private MySingleton(ObjectMapper mapper)
    {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    private static final class Lazy
    {
        static final MySingleton INSTANCE = new MySingleton();
    }

    public static MySingleton getInstance()
    {
        return Lazy.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Now - that is great - and that works - but what if I am trying to test this in a unit test...

I want to mock the mapper - so I can do :

```
ObjectMapper mockObjectMapper = mock(ObjectMapper.class)
```

But, then when I need to somehow call the constructor of "MySingleton" in order to test it...

How do I do that - given that from my test class, I know it will say "MySingleton(arguments here) has private access in MySingleton"?

Comment: Exactly what requirements are you trying to test? I don't see any logic in any of these methods that it would make sense to test.  Usually, trying to test one-line methods is a complete waste of time.

Comment: "I have left out the "if null" logic here" If you're using the lazy holder idiom, you shouldn't need any "if null" logic.

Comment: Look at PowerMock framework.

Comment: @AndyTurner - you are indeed correct - I can pull that code out completely - but do you have any advice for my question? I am kind of baffled at how I might begin testing...

Comment: @tsolakp - I am unsure about how that would get past my "static" problem?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem - I mean, the question does say "Like this" - the question is written in a way so at to not overcomplicate stackoverflow with unnecessary code - I just need to know how to create my instance from a test class.

Comment: @MickeyThreeSheds PowerMock will allow you to mock `new ObjectMapper` call and allow you pass the `mockObjectMapper` instead.

Comment: Well you've designed this class so that the only way to get an instance of it is with the `getInstance` method, so that's what you'll have to use.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem - cool - but is there a way to adapt this type of code to also be able to take arguments when creating the instance?

Comment: You could provide another implementation of `getInstance` but you'd start to lose the point of having a singleton.

Comment: What about using @VisibleForTesting on the constructor that can take arguments? I really only need the arguments for the sake of unit testing is the thing...

Comment: Perhaps the best solution for problems like this is to use a dependency injection framework like Dagger 2 or Guice since they can manage Singletons for you without you

Answer (score 0):

Singletons are the enemies of testable code. The links given in the answer to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085953/unit-testing-with-singletons) are an excellent argumentation on what's evil with singletons as well as why and how to avoid them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **PowerMock** to inject your test ObjectMapper instance using ConstructorMocking.

http://benkiefer.com/blog/2013/04/23/powermockito-constructor-mocking/

I had to modify your example singleton so that the constructors were chained correctly.

```
public class MySingleton {
  ObjectMapper mapper;

  private MySingleton()
   {
      //This does not work.
      //new MySingleton(new ObjectMapper());

      this(new ObjectMapper());
   }

  private MySingleton(ObjectMapper mapper)
   {
     this.mapper = mapper;
   }

  private static final class Lazy
   {
     static final MySingleton INSTANCE = new MySingleton();
   }

  public static MySingleton getInstance()
   {
      return Lazy.INSTANCE;
   }
}
```

I also stubbed the ObjectMapper Class.

```
public class ObjectMapper {
    //Empty Sample uses default CTR
}
```

I was able to test this as follows using the instructions from the link previously listed:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;


@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) 
@PrepareForTest(MySingleton.class) 
public class MySingletonTest {


    @Test
    public void testSingletonCtr() throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        PowerMockito.whenNew(ObjectMapper.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mapper);

        Assert.assertEquals(MySingleton.getInstance().mapper, mapper);
    } 
}
```

I am doing this in a maven project.  I needed the following dependencies added to my test scope:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4-rule</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I do tend to agree that Singletons tend to cause problems long-term for code maintenance and scalability.  If you have capacity to look for alternative approaches to your problem it may benefit you to do so.  If not, then I believe that the **PowerMock** utility will provide you the capability you're looking for.

Best of Luck.